How to match a string that contains a keyword using AST in C++?
Given the example code:
auto a = translate("Hello World");
auto b = translate("Hello Kitty");
auto c = translate("Run Kitty");

I'm trying to create a matcher to find all code that calls translate, where the argument contains Hello. However, with the code below, I'm only able to find all translate function calls:
callExpr(
      callee(functionDecl(hasName("translate"))),
             hasArgument(0, stringLiteral())));

I looked into the ast reference but I did not find any api  that can match a partial string.
I'm new to AST but I think there should be a way to achieve my goal.
I'd appreciate any help.

I've never used this kind of stuff,, so take this with a grain of salt. In general, a syntax tree doesn't care about details: it records a "string", but doesn't care what the string is. As such, I doubt you can find matchers for contents of string literals -- I suggest you just grab all the matching functions, and just loop over them to find the ones with the string literals that you need.

It is not possible to restrict StringLiteral matches based on the contents of the string using a Clang AST Matcher expression.
The only matcher that operates specifically on StringLiteral is hasSize, which restricts based on the number of elements of the array that the string denotes.  (That there is no other StringLiteral matcher can be seen both by reviewing the list in the documentation, and searching for StringLiteral inside ASTMatchersInternal.h.  And restricting by string contents would have to be specific to StringLiteral because the information is inside that class only.)  The matcher expression language is frustratingly incomplete, with matchers seemingly existing for whichever fields someone had a specific need for at some point, thereby leaving many gaps in coverage.
If you are feeding this matcher expression to clang-query, then you're basically stuck.  But if the matcher expression is part of a C++ program using Clang as a library, for example to be integrated with clang-tidy as described at the Contributing page, then you can use the matcher expression to first find all calls to translate (as you've already done), then iterate over the matches, examining the argument StringLiteral objects using the C++ API to look for those containing the substring of interest, presumbly by calling the getString() method.

Could you please share an example of such integration?
I'm assuming that I can add additional customized matcher following the stringliteral() matcher?

There is an example in the linked documentation, specifically in the Writing a clang-tidy Check section.
